# AngularJS error handling when resolving stuff inside the router?

Tags: angularjs, routes

I've been doing lots of research on how to deal with errors best. Let's assume I have this AngularjS code:

$routeProvider

```
.when('/videomail/:key', {
    templateUrl : 'view.html',
    controller  : 'ViewCtrl',
    title       : 'View',
    hideHeader  : true,
    hideFooter  : true,
    resolve: {
        videomail: function($rootScope, $route, Videomail) {
            return Videomail.get({key: $route.current.params.key}).$promise.then(function(videomail) {
                return videomail
            }, function(err) {
                // How can I present the error here?
                // Should I return it like 'return err' and let the controller deal with it?
                // Or can I forward this to another controller?
                // PS: It can be a 404 or a 401 error 
            })
        }
    }
})
```

Check out the questions in the comments. Any clues, hints are very welcome!!

Comment: you want to do it in general for all aplication error handling or only for this route ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you don't want the route to change, and you don't want to handle the error in the controller, you can do this:

- Resolve the promise with something that is unambiguously an error. You have to resolve the promise because if you don't, the route will not be loaded at all, and you can't change that in `$routeChangeError`.

  ```
  videomail: function($rootScope, $route, Videomail) {
      return Videomail.get({key: $route.current.params.key}).$promise.then(function(videomail) {
          return videomail
      }, function(err) {
          return { resolveError: err }
      })
  }
  ```
- Somewhere in the app (maybe in `run`), intercept `$routeChangeSuccess` and check if an error occured.

  ```
  $rootScope.$on('$routeChangeSuccess', 
      function (event, current, previous) {
          if (current.locals.videomail && current.locals.videomail.resolveError) {
              current.locals.$template = $templateCache.get('error.html')
              $rootScope.error = current.locals.videomail.resolveError
          }
      }
  )
  ```

Now you just have to write a template named `error.html` that will display something depending on the `error` object present in the scope.

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/u9mybo58/2/)

It works but I think it is kind of a hack. I don't believe Angular was meant to be used that way.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `$location` service to redirect to another route.

```
return Videomail.get({key: $route.current.params.key}).$promise.then(function(videomail) {
    return videomail
}, function(err) {
    $location.path('/error')
})
```

Comment: Thanks, good idea. But how can I pass on the err object to the new error page? Or should I be using the $routeChangeError event instead?

Comment: You pass the error members in the URL with `$location.search`. `$routeChangeError` is another possibility if you want to handle errors application-wide.

Comment: I just played and $location.path() is not what I want. Because it's a redirect, the URL changes. But I want the URL to stay.

Comment: So I assume $routeChangeError is the solution for me but I haven't figured out how I can set a template inside the $routeChangeError event handler?

Comment: As far as I know, you cannot do that. If a promise is rejected, the controller and the view for the route are not loaded at all. The only thing you can do is redirect.

Comment: So if you really want the URL not to change, resolve the promise with the error (using `return error` in the callback) and let the controller handle it.

Comment: Yes, I do not want to change the URL. And letting the controller handle it, is not an option for me either because I have many controllers here. Do not want to duplicate too much code. All I need to know is how to set a template inside the $routeChangeError event handler!